# Compose: Proper way of extending the RowScope Modifier? (Or any Scope Modifier for that matter)

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, extension-methods

I'm creating a *Row* of *Text* Composables, imagine it like a table row.
Image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR3oB.png](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

**If you care for the backstory:**
The amount of "cells" of my custom *Row* Composable is dynamic and I use *Box* Composables to wrap the *Text* in the "cells". I need to apply different *Modifier* parameters to each *Box*, which I first tried to achieve via creating a *Modifier* extension.

**Code of my *Modifier* extension:**

```
@SuppressLint("ComposableModifierFactory", "ModifierFactoryExtensionFunction") // I wish I could. The RowScope requirement makes doing it the easy way impossible
@Composable
fun RowScope.rowOfTextCellsBoxModifier(
    index: Int,
    columnWidths: ArrayList<Dp?>,
    columnWeights: ArrayList<Float?>
): Modifier {
    @Suppress("RedundantExplicitType") // bull**** (compose kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 1.3.2)
    var returnModifier: Modifier = Modifier

    if (index != columnWidths.size - 1)
        returnModifier = returnModifier.then(Modifier.verticalEndLine())

    returnModifier = if (columnWidths[index] != null)
        returnModifier.then(Modifier.width(columnWidths[index]!!))
    else {
        val weight = try {
            columnWeights[index]
        } catch (ignored: Throwable) {
            1f
        }
        returnModifier.then(Modifier.weight(weight!!))
    }

    return returnModifier
}
```

I moved on to just generating the entire *Box* in a @Composable function, but that's beside the point ;)

**As you can see, I want to add a *Modifier.weight()* at one point.**

However, *.weight()* is a *Modifier* function that is only applicable in certain Scopes, like in *RowScope*. Which means that my "*Modifier* extension" needs to apply to *RowScope*, which turned out impossible to find instructions on.

So, imagine I hadn't found a better solution:
**What would be the proper way of extending the *RowScope* Interface's *Modifier*?**

---

Usually, when you need to create a Composable that is applicable to certain scopes, you write something like:
`RowScope.YourComposable() {...}`

And when you extend *Modifier*, you write:
`Modifier.yourExtension() {...}`

But that does not work for Scoped *Modifiers*:

`RowScope.Modifier.YourModifierExtension() {...}`
is invalid code.

Comment: You could pass the scope to the function (+ use `with`/`run`) or try the experimental [context receiver](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/context-receivers.md).

Comment: @gpunto Yes, there exist two or possibly more workarounds for this issue. However, the question at hand still stands. I suspect that this kind of scoped Modifier extension is limited by how Kotlin handles Interfaces and Scopes too.

(Writing a Modifier extension that correctly applies to the Modifier of RowScope or any other specific scope seems like a very specific demand to make to the language functionalities.)

Comment: Why do you say it's a workaround? The context receiver language feature I linked allows you to do what you asked.

Comment: Thanks @gpunto, you're right, the experimental context receiver solves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A viable experimental solution at the time of writing is to use the **experimental Context Receiver** to make the Modifier applicable to a specific Scope. Thanks to user @gpunto for the hint.

See [this Github page](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/context-receivers.md) for further details on the Context Receiver.

You can implement the experimental feature by adding `"-Xcontext-receivers"` to the Kotlin compiler options. In an android project using Gradle (Kotlin DSL), this is done by adding it to the kotlinOptions "freeCompilerArgs" list:

```
kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xcontext-receivers")
}
```

Usage for my example in the question is as follows:

```
context(RowScope) private fun Modifier.rowOfTextCellsBoxModifier(
    index: Int,
    columnWidths: ArrayList<Dp?>,
    columnWeights: ArrayList<Float?>,
    columTextsSize: Int
): Modifier {
    return this
        .then(if (index != columTextsSize - 1) Modifier.verticalEndLine() else Modifier)
        .then(
            if (columnWidths[index] != null)
                Modifier.width(columnWidths[index]!!)
            else {
                val weight = try {
                    columnWeights[index]
                } catch (ignored: Throwable) {
                    1f
                }
                Modifier.weight(weight!!)
            }
        )
}
```

**What the context receiver does:**

It allows the use of the `.weight` modifier while the extension functions still targets the `Modifier` interface as recommended.

This would also allow you to use the `= composed {}` functionalities.

This solution results in the cleanest, least hacky code with zero lint complaints. Whether to use this in production is up to your judgement however.

**Differences to the code example in my question:**

This now uses Compose compiler version 1.4.3.

Instead of allocating a new instance of a Modifier, adding to it with `.then()` and returning that allocated instance, the code now returns the Modifier receiver (`this`) with conditionally applied Modifiers in `.then()` calls.